# Bluetooth issues compiling with gcc on RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, c, gcc, bluetooth, raspbian

I'm using Raspbian (Debian Wheezy). I've installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools bluez-dbg bluez-hcidump bluez-tools python-bluez libbluetooth-dev libbluetooth3 libbluetooth3-dbg
```

but when trying to compile the following line, it says it doesn't know of the library:

```
$ gcc scanbd.c -o scanbd
/tmp/ccl5BrFc.o: In function `main':
scanbd.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `hci_get_route'
scanbd.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `hci_open_dev'
scanbd.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `hci_inquiry'
scanbd.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `ba2str'
scanbd.c:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `hci_read_remote_name'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are the include statements I have in my .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

UPDATE: It turns out that I did all the right things but I had to shutdown/unplug the RPi and then restart for everything to work just fine... the -lbluetooth was in the path after that.
Thanks guys

Comment: it's not enough to install the Bluetooth libraries, you also need to link them to your program. Add `-lbluetooth` to your compiler command and the undefined reference errors will vanish.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I compiled using the line "# gcc -o scanbd scanbd.c -lbluetooth". It said that no such file or directory "bluetooth". What is the file extension of the bluetooth library file? Maybe I can search and see if it's installed at all. Or maybe that it's not in the path? Although I did add the /usr/include and /usr/library paths. I got the hci_* errors when I removed the -lbluetooth library from the compiler command. As I mentioned, when I add the -lbluetooth back in, it says it doesn't know of it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output when you append the `-lbluetooth` to your gcc command?    `gcc -o scanbd scanbd.c -lbluetooth`  (that's DASH ELL BEE ELL EWE EEE... etc)

Answer (score 0):

Hopes below links can help you.

[Linking with libbluetooth.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736762/linking-with-libbluetooth-so)

When you compile, please put parameter -lbluetooth after scannbd.c as below:

Ex:
gcc scanbd.c -lbluetooth -o scanbd